# How to solve string operation failure on a string

Tags: php, datetime

I'm extracting a string from xml. It is a templated string. When I try to perform string operations on this string, none of the operations are working.

```
<script id="template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
<table>    
<tr>
    <th>Posted on: </th>
    <td><?php $date1='{{posted}}';echo $date1 ;echo date("j-F-Y", strtotime($date1));?></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</script>
```

The above code contains `{{posted}}` with date in string format something like 2013-04-12. When I try strtotime() it fails and returns false. When I try str_replace(), even this fails. How to solve this problem. As I need to convert the each date from the Y-m-d to d-M-Y format

Answer (score 0):

First, check your variable **$date1** format, if it contains like: **2013/12/18** then you have to replace **"/"** with **"-"** then convert your date as per your (format) wish.

Check your code is in this format:

```
echo date("Y-m-d", strtotime("2013-12-18"));

echo date("j-F-Y", strtotime($date1));
```

Comment: I have mentioned it is in 2013-12-18 format. But, still `strtotime()` fails

Comment: strtotime() returns -1, so it displays 01-January-1970